# Store data from API in variable [Angular]

Tags: angular, http

I have a service which gets data from API : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

but i can not store data in variable

Code :
Service.ts

```
public urlServer : string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

public getAllProjectsFromAPI() : Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get( this.urlServer, { responseType: 'json' } ); 
}
```

Component.ts

```
constructor( private projects : ProjetsService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projects.getAllProjectsFromAPI().subscribe( data => this.test = JSON.stringify( data ) );
    console.log( this.test );
  }
```

I try to console test var and i get undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are trying to log a value which is not yet computed.

```
// this block is asynchronous
this.projects.getAllProjectsFromAPI().subscribe( 
  data => this.test = JSON.stringify( data )
);
// this line is synchronous
console.log( this.test );
```

Execute your code in the asynchronous block:

```
this.projects.getAllProjectsFromAPI().subscribe(data => { 
  this.test = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(this.test)
});
```

Note that I added `{}` in order to execute multiple lines in the observable callback.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i would like show test variable in my html file is it possible in my case.

Comment: In your component template file: `<div>{{test}}</div>`. Please accept the answer if it fits your need.

Comment: Thank you but can i have more details.It work's in HTML file but i don't understand why. Indeed the code that i want to execute is asynchronous and HTML too ?

Comment: I really encourage you to take take a look at the official tutorial to better understand Angular https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: It will work in HTML file because the value is already loaded. Assign a dummy value on `{{test}}` before calling the API and then you will see that the value will change asynchronously.