# How to store a variable in angular which is being subscribed via post as json?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have a json as like this.

```
[{"id":"1","date":"2020-02-21","status":"present","studentid":"1"},{"id":"2","date":"2020-02-24","status":"present","studentid":"1"}]
```

How to store date in a  variable using angular which is being subscribe d as http request.I am not able to store .This is what i tried.

```
 date:string=[];
 sendPostRequest()  {

  var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }) };
   var count=0;
  this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=getattendance", this.postData,options).
  pipe(map(res =>  res.results || []))

  .subscribe(data => {
   this.date=data['date'];


  });
```

please help me.I am new to angular.

Comment: what do you mean by global variable? across the application?

Comment: sorry i mean store it in a variable which is outside subscribe method .here store it in date.

Comment: @Kaustubh Khare .This json value keeps on changing by having more number of data.So how can i make it dynamic

Comment: just loop through the data that you are receiving inside subscribe function. It will be dynamic

Comment: @midhunsivarajan Yes. I understood that. Check my answer.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare can you please help me by telling the code how to store data in a variable  which is being subscribed via http

Comment: @midhunsivarajan I have updated my answer. Please try that and let me know if you get any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting response as an array. Convert your response to date. Please refer below code where you will get the date from your response.

```
date:string=[];
 sendPostRequest()  {

  var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }) };
   var count=0;
  this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=getattendance", this.postData,options).
  pipe(map(res =>  res.results || []))

  .subscribe(data => {
   this.date=data.map(ele => ele.date);


  });
```

Example,

```js
const data = [{"id":"1","date":"2020-02-21","status":"present","studentid":"1"},{"id":"2","date":"2020-02-24","status":"present","studentid":"1"}];

const date = data.map(ele => ele.date);

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through this json and put it into a new array.

```js
const json = [{ "id": "1", "date": "2020-02-21", "status": "present", "studentid": "1" }, { "id": "2", "date": "2020-02-24", "status": "present", "studentid": "1" }];
const date = [];
json.forEach((item) => {
    date.push({
        date: item.date
    })
})
console.log(date);
```

Comment: this json i am getting while subscribing.Can you please help me by telling how to store the data which is being accepted by subscription

Comment: This problem is related to the deep and shallow copy of the object. You can learn about this information

Answer (score 0):

your date in string format and it's a single value and declare your date variable as Array [] you just need to declare your date as string variable

date : string ='';
or 
date = '';

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is similar to these already asked questions. If you want to store it in a variable you can look at this one: [Store data from API in variable [Angular]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811230/store-data-from-api-in-variable-angular)

If you want to convert it in date format have a look at it:
[how to convert current date to YYYY-MM-DD format with angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630445/how-to-convert-current-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-with-angular-2/43630479)

**UPDATE**

I think the only problem is not iterating properly. Something like this would be okay.

Iterate over your response and push the element to your list

```
.subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach((item) => {
      date.push({
          date: item.date
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.but i want only date.not the entire json.can you please help me by telling how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Understand the structure of your JSON well at first. For that you can use online JSON parser available for free:

> https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer
>
> https://jsonformatter.org/
>
> http://json.parser.online.fr/

If you see you data after structure it is;

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "date": "2020-02-21",
    "status": "present",
    "studentid": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "date": "2020-02-24",
    "status": "present",
    "studentid": "1"
  }
```

]

There is an array of object. So basically, you have too loop through the array visit every index of array and then pick the key-value pair that you want.

@wsc answer pointed the code well.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an array of objects.
Define your date variable as data:string='';

and try this.date=data[0].date

if you get any error please update.

Answer (score 0):

```
    date:string=[];
 sendPostRequest()  {

  var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }) };
   var count=0;
  this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=getattendance", this.postData,options).
  pipe(map(res =>  res.results || []))

  .subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(element=>{
this.date.push(element.date);
})
```

});